# Parsing xml response to pandas dataframe and dictionary

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

My response is a well-shaped .xml file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Record key="XXXXX" req_sym="AAPL-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE FIRST STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Record key="YYYYY" req_sym="AI-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE SECOND STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Record key="ZZZZZ" req_sym="MSFT-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE THIRD STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Request>
      <RequestedReports>'search'</RequestedReports>
      <SearchGUID>'D207EF2FB41023D5'</SearchGUID>
      <RequestedStartDate>'20231010'</RequestedStartDate>
      <RequestedEndDate>'20231016'</RequestedEndDate>
  </Request>
  <Error description="" code="200"/>
</Response>
```

How do I parse this response into:

1. a pandas dataframe with each <Record> as a row, with 'Field id' as index and ['HEADLINE', 'SOURCE', 'STORY_DATE'] as columns
2. a dictionary to store meta data inside the <Request> tag

Comment: For the 2nd part of your question, you might want to look at the `xmltodict` module.

Answer (score 0):

Use a powershell script to create a csv file and then import the csv

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$records = $doc.Descendants("Record")

foreach($record in $records)
{
   $key = $record.Attribute('key').Value
   $req_sym = $record.Attribute('req_sym').Value

   foreach($Field in $record.Descendants("Field"))
   {
      $id = $Field.Attribute('id').Value
      $name = $Field.Attribute('name').Value
      $value = $Field.Attribute('value').Value
  
      $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
         key = $key
         req_sym = $req_sym
         id = $id
         name = $name
         value = $value
      }
      $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
   }
}
$table | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas and xpath can read all the content into a table, or only specific parts and convert it to dict:

```
import pandas as pd

xml="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Record key="XXXXX" req_sym="AAPL-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE FIRST STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Record key="YYYYY" req_sym="AI-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE SECOND STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Record key="ZZZZZ" req_sym="MSFT-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE THIRD STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Request>
      <RequestedReports>'search'</RequestedReports>
      <SearchGUID>'D207EF2FB41023D5'</SearchGUID>
      <RequestedStartDate>'20231010'</RequestedStartDate>
      <RequestedEndDate>'20231016'</RequestedEndDate>
  </Request>
  <Error description="" code="200"/>
</Response>"""

# get all Record in a table
df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='.//Record')
print(df)

# get requests content ant change it to dict
df1 = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='.//Request')
df2 = df1.to_dict('records')
print(df2)
```

The dataframe and dictionary looks like:

```
     key  req_sym  Fields
0  XXXXX  AAPL-US     NaN
1  YYYYY    AI-US     NaN
2  ZZZZZ  MSFT-US     NaN

[{'RequestedReports': "'search'", 'SearchGUID': "'D207EF2FB41023D5'", 'RequestedStartDate': "'20231010'", 'RequestedEndDate': "'20231016'"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using `beautifulsoup`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_file = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Record key="XXXXX" req_sym="AAPL-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE FIRST STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Record key="YYYYY" req_sym="AI-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE SECOND STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Record key="ZZZZZ" req_sym="MSFT-US">
    <Fields>
      <Field id="7000" name="HEADLINE" value="THIS IS THE THIRD STORY" />
      <Field id="7001" name="SOURCE" value="EDG" />
      <Field id="7004" name="STORY_DATE" value="20231010" />
    </Fields>
  </Record>
  <Request>
      <RequestedReports>'search'</RequestedReports>
      <SearchGUID>'D207EF2FB41023D5'</SearchGUID>
      <RequestedStartDate>'20231010'</RequestedStartDate>
      <RequestedEndDate>'20231016'</RequestedEndDate>
  </Request>
  <Error description="" code="200"/>
</Response>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, "xml")

all_data = []
for record in soup.select("Record"):
    d = {"Index": []}
    for f in record.select("Field"):
        d["Index"].append(f["id"])
        d[f["name"]] = f["value"]
    all_data.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                Index                  HEADLINE SOURCE STORY_DATE
0  [7000, 7001, 7004]   THIS IS THE FIRST STORY    EDG   20231010
1  [7000, 7001, 7004]  THIS IS THE SECOND STORY    EDG   20231010
2  [7000, 7001, 7004]   THIS IS THE THIRD STORY    EDG   20231010
```